# flask wtform validation fails

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

```
class FlowerForm(FlaskForm):
    cr_score = IntegerField('Credit Score', validators=[DataRequired()])
    geo = StringField('Geography', validators=[DataRequired()])
    gen = StringField('Gender', validators=[DataRequired()])
    age = IntegerField('Age', validators=[DataRequired()])
    ten = IntegerField('Tenure', validators=[DataRequired()])
    bal = IntegerField('Balance', validators=[DataRequired()])
    num = IntegerField('Number Of Products', validators=[DataRequired()])
    has_card = IntegerField('Has Credit Card', validators=[DataRequired()])
    is_active = IntegerField('Is Active Member', validators=[DataRequired()])
    sal = IntegerField('Estimated Salary', validators=[DataRequired()])
    
    submit = SubmitField('Analyze')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    # Create instance of the form.
    form = FlowerForm(request.form)
    # If the form is valid on submission
    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate_on_submit():
   
        # Grab the data from the input on the form.
        session["cr_score"] = form.cr_score.data
        session["geo"] = form.geo.data
        session["gen"] = form.gen.data
        session["age"] = form.age.data
        session["ten"] = form.ten.data
        session["bal"] = form.bal.data
        session["num"] = form.num.data
        session["has_card"] = form.has_card.data
        session["is_active"] = form.is_active.data
        session["sal"] = form.sal.data
        
        return redirect(url_for("prediction"))
    print(form.errors)
    return render_template('home.html', form=form)

@app.route('/prediction')
def prediction():
    #Defining content dictionary
    content = {}
    
    content["CreditScore"] = int(session["cr_score"])
    content["Geography"] = str(session["geo"])
    content["Gender"] = str(session["gen"])
    content["Age"] = int(session["age"])
    content["Tenure"] = int(session["ten"])
    content["Balance"] = int(session["bal"])
    content["NumOfProducts"] = int(session["num"])
    content["HasCrCard"] = int(session["has_card"])
    content["IsActiveMember"] = int(session["is_active"])
    content["EstimatedSalary"] = int(session["sal"])


    results = return_prediction(model = model, scaler = scaler, onehot = ohencoder, lab_enc=labencoder, sample_json = content)
    return render_template('prediction.html',results=results)
```

The form validation does not seem to work here.
I've tried `form.valid_on_submit` too.

My home.html file and prediction.html file both have `form.hidden_tag()` in it.

The if statement gets overriden somehow and I end up back on the home page

HTML `home.html` code:

```
<h1>Welcome to Customer Retention Prediction</h1>
<h2>Please enter customer details below:</h2>
<form action = "/" method=”POST”>
 {# This hidden_tag is a CSRF security feature. #}
 {{form.hidden_tag()}}
 {{ form.csrf_token }}
 {{form.cr_score.label}} {{form.cr_score}}
 <br>
 {{form.geo.label}} {{form.geo}}
 <br>
 {{form.gen.label}} {{form.gen}}
 <br>
 {{form.age.label}} {{form.age}}
 <br>
 {{form.ten.label}} {{form.ten}}
 <br>
 {{form.bal.label}} {{form.bal}}
 <br>
 {{form.num.label}} {{form.num}}
 <br>
 {{form.has_card.label}}{{form.has_card}}
 <br>
 {{form.is_active.label}} {{form.is_active}}
 <br>
 {{form.sal.label}} {{form.sal}}
 <br>
 {{form.submit()}}
</form>
```

`prediction.html` code:

```
<h1>Thank You.</h1>
 {# This hidden_tag is a CSRF security feature. #}
 {{form.hidden_tag()}}
<h2>Probability of this customer leaving the bank is: {{results}}</h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried printing the error
After the if statement try `print(form.errors)` , it should give you error `no crsf token`.

In html add this where you used `form.hidden_tag()`
Below it use `{{ form.csrf_token }}`

```
[...]
if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():
        # Grab the data from the input on the form.
        session["cr_score"] = form.cr_score.data
        session["geo"] = form.geo.data
        session["gen"] = form.gen.data
        session["age"] = form.age.data
        [....]
print(form.errors)
return render_template('home.html', form=form)
```

Edit: you are not using action in form tag.

In html file: it should be this

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
```

your index function will be:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    # Create instance of the form.
    form = FlowerForm(request.form)
    # If the form is valid on submission
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("yoyo")
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            
            # Grab the data from the input on the form.
            session["cr_score"] = form.cr_score.data
            session["geo"] = form.geo.data
            session["gen"] = form.gen.data
            session["age"] = form.age.data
            session["ten"] = form.ten.data
            session["bal"] = form.bal.data
            session["num"] = form.num.data
            session["has_card"] = form.has_card.data
            session["is_active"] = form.is_active.data
            session["sal"] = form.sal.data
            
            return redirect(url_for("prediction"))
    print(form.errors)
    return render_template('home.html', form=form)
```

Your home.html will be:

```
<h1>Welcome to Customer Retention Prediction</h1>
<h2>Please enter customer details below:</h2>
<form action="/" method="POST">
 {# This hidden_tag is a CSRF security feature. #}
 {{form.hidden_tag()}}

 {{ form.csrf_token }}
 {{form.cr_score.label}} {{form.cr_score}}
 <br>
 {{form.geo.label}} {{form.geo}}
 <br>
 {{form.gen.label}} {{form.gen}}
 <br>
 {{form.age.label}} {{form.age}}
 <br>
 {{form.ten.label}} {{form.ten}}
 <br>
 {{form.bal.label}} {{form.bal}}
 <br>
 {{form.num.label}} {{form.num}}
 <br>
 {{form.has_card.label}}{{form.has_card}}
 <br>
 {{form.is_active.label}} {{form.is_active}}
 <br>
 {{form.sal.label}} {{form.sal}}
 <br>
 {{form.submit()}}
  {{form.errors}}
</form>
```

Comment: i tried using `form.errors`, but i'm getting no errors printed whatsoever. It's the same as before and i get redirected to the `home.html` page without any errors.

Comment: where are you printing the form.errors, can you update the code with the current code you are using

Comment: it's done. i've added it just after the if statement like you said

Comment: no you don't have to add it here , I mean after the if statement scope , I updated the answer, you can see

Comment: it's the same even after changing the location of the `form.errors` code

Comment: what did it printed after changing the location of form.errors. is it empty dict or error in it?, and  can you provide the html code where you are using forms.

Comment: It didn't print anything. It just took me back to the `home.html` page. I've added both the html codes above as well

Comment: print(form.errros) might have printed blank dict or one containing error. I don't think so you are printing form.errors at the right place. Can you share upload your code on github and share it's link ,or dm me on discord if you want it to be private `charchit#8198`

Comment: yea. i've uploaded it on github. this is the link: https://github.com/yashsandansing/churn_modelling2

Comment: @YashSandansing I edited the answer,  also you need to input correct datatype as per forms , integer for integer and string for string.

Comment: I tried it with the edits too. Still no response. The input datatype is correct too but I'm just not getting any errors or response whatsoever.

Comment: you have to use `form.validate_on_submit()` can you update the code and post the code which you are using now.

Comment: I've posted the edited code here itself. I tried using `from.validate_on_submit()` with and without `form action == POST` but it's giving the same result.

Comment: I think there is something I am missing in your code. no error seems to be there. but the same code is working on mine.I edited the answer and pasted the main part. You can give a try.

Comment: I've tried running it with the updated code too. Would you mind telling me if you get the prediction.html page rendered?

Comment: I tried running the code when I submit it gives me error in numpy or tensorflow. You can try testing you numpy tensorflow code without flask.